# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может не работать анимация transition

Tags: java, android, transition

-7
down vote
favorite

при переходе из сетки во viewPager анимация работает корректно, но при переходе в обратную сторону, работает только анимация плавного затемнения Fade, с чем это может быть связанно? Вот мой код самого перехода во ViewPager

```
 class ConnectToSlider implements OnClickHolder{
    @Override
    public void openSlider(int position,View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "openSlider: GO FRAGMENT");
        ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
        imageView.setTransitionName(String.valueOf(Images.resInts.get(position)));
        SliderFragment slider = new SliderFragment();
        ((TransitionSet) MainActivity.getCurrentFragment().getExitTransition()).excludeTarget(v, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "TRANSITION NAME: " + v.getTransitionName());
            Log.d(TAG, "VIEW: " + v);
            Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_transition);
            slider.setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .addSharedElement(imageView,imageView.getTransitionName())
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, slider);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
}
```

Ниже представлен код самого ViewPagerFragment

```
   public class SliderFragment extends Fragment {



 private static final String TAG = "SliderFragment";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ");
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slider,container,false);
        AdapterSliderPager adapter = new AdapterSliderPager(this);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(MainActivity.currentFragmentNumber);
//        prepareTransition();
//        postponeEnterTransition();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "INSTANSE STATE NULL, START POSTPONE ENTER TRANSITION");
            postponeEnterTransition();
        }
        return pager;
    }
```

и код вложенного фрагмента который генерирует ViewPager

```
public class BigFotoFragment extends Fragment {
private int imageUrl;
public int getImageUrl() {return imageUrl;}
public void setImageUrl(int imageUrl) {this.imageUrl = imageUrl;}
private static final String TAG = "BigFotoFragment";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_big_foto,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.bigPhotoContainer);
    imageView.setTransitionName(String.valueOf(imageUrl));
    imageView.setImageResource(imageUrl);
    getParentFragment().startPostponedEnterTransition();
    Log.d(TAG, "TRANSITION NAME: " + imageView.getTransitionName());
    return view;
}
```